# probability of coin landing on tails less than 230 times out of 500, and more than 270 out of 500?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've been stuck on figuring out how to do this with binomial distribution. I know i have to use it, but not how. Is there someone who can help?

Comment: Well, with the binomial distribution it's just a matter of brute force (summing $230$ terms).  Not difficult, with a machine.  The standard formulas apply.  Of course, the normal approximation is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a fair coin is used and trials are independent,
$$X\sim B(500,0.5)$$
where $X$ represents the number of tails thrown out of $500$ throws. For the probabilities desired
$$P(X\lt230)=\sum_{k=0}^{229}P(X=k)=0.03330483$$
$$P(X\gt270)=\sum_{k=271}^{500}P(X=k)=0.03330483$$
They are equal in probability because for any distribution $Y\sim B(n,0.5)$ we have that
$$P(Y\le k)=P(Y\ge n-k)$$